# Search API creation in Django Restframework

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am learning Django and Restframework. My OS is MS-Windows 7 Professional. I am working on Python2.7+. 
I wanted to learn how to make an API on REST with Python. I chose above mentioned path. 
To learn REST I could do the Quickstart tutorial, and could build a browsable API. 
As I found there are serializers.py, views.py, and urls.py. I feel the functionality of a model depends based on which Django libraries I call in serializers.py. 
Again the functionality of each Django library is predefined, thus I can not change user, email, etc. to some other like text input or some other.

After building browsable API I wanted to make a search API, where I would be able to key in some character strings and boolean queries. 
I was looking to change the Django library that I was calling in serializers.py, but without much success.
I tried to browse through web or your previous posts and Restframework tutorial but did not find much help. 
If any one may kindly suggest me how should I approach this problem it would be of great help. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is built right into django-rest-framework. Take a look at some of the examples in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter). Is that what you're looking for?